# python error on npm package install Windows

Tags: windows, npm

On Windows, When I try to install wdio, I have a python error : 
but python is installed and in the path.
the PYTHON variable is set to "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe", which is a correct path. 
I don't know where the error is coming from, since it says it can find the executable, bit show the right path to the executable.

```
PS C:\Users\admin> npm install wdio

> fibers@1.0.15 install C:\Users\admin\node_modules\fibers
> node build.js || nodejs build.js


C:\Users\admin\node_modules\fibers>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild --release )  else (node "" rebuild --release )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\admin\node_modules\fibers
gyp ERR! node -v v8.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.1
gyp ERR! not ok
node-gyp exited with code: 1
Please make sure you are using a supported platform and node version. If you
would like to compile fibers on this machine please make sure you have setup your
build environment--
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\admin\package.json'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [Python 2.7](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) since node-gyp is not compatible with Python 3.x. See e.g. https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows

Answer (score 0):

I had to reinstall node when I had similar issue ( this just updated to the current stable) Although before that I had updated every other thing while trying a solution including python for windows and node-gyp (`npm install -g node-gyp`). The node js update finally did it